# Send Arraylist containing sum(column) to jsp

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanna add the sum of all the entries of a column to an ArrayList and forward that arrayList to a jsp.
I used sum(column name) and entered this value in ArrayList as follows:

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select e_id,sum(work_duration) as sumtotal from emp_diary group by e_id");
List<List<String>> report=new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
                    row.add(rs.getString(1));
                    row.add(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("sumtotal")));
                    report.add(row);
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("report.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

I have successfully entered both the values to Arraylist
How to proceed further?

The Servlet does not run as i write the last line i.e. `rd.forward(request,response);`
It runs when i remove this line and thus does not go to the jsp.

Comment: Please explain *RequestDispatcher not working!*. We don't have a magic crystal ball that will help us to foresee your code and what happens there. If there's more code to add and an exception or something else that help us analyze the problem, **please add them to the question** (not in comments).

Comment: Are you getting some error ?

Comment: What error do you get? Is there a stacktrace to analyze? Probably you're doing both forward and redirect on the same response, thus getting problems. But we cannot see it since you don't explain your situation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare arraylist as public and use the following code to redirect. and access the arraylist by bean object.

```
response.sendRedirect("report.jsp");
```

Comment: This *solution* is open to issues with multi threading, specially when multiple users execute the same request on this servlet.